# Process.Start() results in Access Denied exception despite Full Control for Everyone group

Tags: c#, windows, permissions

My project output contains an executable called key_gen.exe that I'm trying to run. The executable is not built by the project, but copied in after the fact. With the code below I receive an Access Denied exception.

```
string key_gen_dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory.Substring(0, Environment.CurrentDirectory.LastIndexOf("\\")) + @"\Scripts\key_gen\";

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = key_gen_dir + "key_gen.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(". {0}", password);
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

The FileName value is correct and works when tested in Command Prompt. I do not want to run the program as an administrator. I have tried enabling UseShellExecute, but I receive a PlatformNotSupportedException. The key_gen_dir and all subfiles and folders have FullControl permissions for the Everyone group. If it's relevant, my project is targetted for .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: why do you need a "." (dot) to the arguments? is this how the exe expects the pwd? i think access denial could be by the permission for the app that is triggering this, when compared to you trying from cmd prompt. UAC settings may come into picture. Is the keygen.exe is allowed to run by your app and under what user type your app would run?

Comment: The dot is an expected argument. The keygen.exe is a small python script I wrote, packaged into a distributable executable. I would assume keygen.exe should be able to be run by my app. The app is inteded to be run as a standard user, but I'm not sure if that's how Visual Studio runs the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the access denied error by editing the file properties in Windows and adding the ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES group to the file permissions with Read & Execute allowed.